# JAXB unmarshal returning null values

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using JAXB to convert XML file to java object

I have looked a lot in the examples on the web but still get null values in my object when I unmarshall it to a java object

what I miss?

```
File file = new File("BootloaderProtocol.xml");

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Command.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Command commanda = (Command) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        System.out.println(commanda);
```

my class:

```
 @XmlRootElement(name="Command")
 public class Command {


String COMMAND_ID;
String COMMAND_NAME;
String COMMAND_CODES;


public String getCOMMAND_ID() {
    return COMMAND_ID;
}

@XmlElement
public void setCOMMAND_ID(String COMMAND_ID) {
    this.COMMAND_ID = COMMAND_ID;
}
public String getCOMMAND_NAME() {
    return COMMAND_NAME;
}

@XmlElement
public void setCOMMAND_NAME(String COMMAND_NAME) {
    this.COMMAND_NAME = COMMAND_NAME;
}

public String getCOMMAND_CODES() {
    return COMMAND_CODES;
}

@XmlElement
public void setCOMMAND_CODES(String COMMAND_CODES) {
    this.COMMAND_CODES = COMMAND_CODES;
}
```

}

and this my XML file:

```
 <Command>
    <COMMAND>
        <COMMAND_ID>0xFE01</COMMAND_ID>
        <COMMAND_NAME>Start bootloader</COMMAND_NAME>
        <COMMAND_CODES>EE120301FE0900</COMMAND_CODES>
    </COMMAND>


  </Command>
```

Comment: Your `Command` class does not reflect the XML structure. The element "COMMAND" is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct xml structure:

```
<Command>
    <COMMAND_ID>0xFE01</COMMAND_ID>
    <COMMAND_NAME>Start bootloader</COMMAND_NAME>
    <COMMAND_CODES>EE120301FE0900</COMMAND_CODES>
</Command>
```

Try your code with this xml. Use the correct path of the xml file in the code.

Btw, I have tested your code with this xml and it works fine.

Comment: still have problems. i added new node to my xml and get the error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed  this is my new xml : <Command>
    <COMMAND_ID>0xFE01</COMMAND_ID>
    <COMMAND_NAME>Start bootloader</COMMAND_NAME>
    <COMMAND_CODES>EE120301FE0900</COMMAND_CODES>
</Command>
<Command>
    <COMMAND_ID>0xFE02</COMMAND_ID>
    <COMMAND_NAME>Start application</COMMAND_NAME>
    <COMMAND_CODES>EE120302FE0900</COMMAND_CODES>
</Command>

Comment: Refer this, http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/30/jaxb-exmaple-marshalling-and-unmarshalling-list-or-set-of-objects/

Comment: Btw your xml structure is wrong you cannot have more than one root element.

Comment: http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java/jaxb/jaxb-marshalling-and-unmarshalling-list-of-objects/

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
public class Command {
    @XmlElement(name="COMMAND")
    public NestedCommand command;

    static class NestedCommand {
        String COMMAND_ID;
```